# Cycle Through Proposals in Eclipse Content Assist

Tags: eclipse, content-assist

Is there a way to change which proposal in the content assistant is selected (other than using the arrow keys or the mouse)? For example, I would like to use tab and shift-tab to cycle down and up the list of suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

If you assign individual content assist proposal kinds to a specific keybinding,

> (Window > Preferences > General > Keys: type 'Content Assist')

such as

> Content Assist (Template Proposals) to Alt+C,

then you can bring up *a single proposal box with this shortcut*.  There will not be an option to cycle through each of the proposal kinds by typing the standard '**Content Assist**' keybinding again.

Once you have that *proposal box pulled up*, you can use the '**Line Down**' and '**Line Up**' keybindings to cycle through that specific proposal kind's options, *all without moving your hand over to the arrow keys.*

It seems to work well if you only use a few of the proposal kinds.

Comment: Thanks, looks much nicer.